# ASP.NET execute WebMethod with Jquery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have one WebMethod that will execute some DB search and return it's data in some HTML template. I need to execute this method using jquery to populate an area of the website but the problem is that my website URL/URI is dynamic.

My URL is `http://site/school-name/home`. The `school-name` will always change to indicate wich school i'm accessing.

I have accomplished so far:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Default.aspx/BuscaEquipe",
    data: { 'pIndex': pIndex, 'pLimite': 4, 'pUnidadeCE': codigoEmitente },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

and the WebMethod:

```
public static string BuscaEquipe(int pIndex, int pLimite, int pUnidadeCE)
{
    var objEquipe = new Equipe { EquipeUnidadeCE = pUnidadeCE, EquipeAtivo = 1 };
    var CaminhoImagem = Configuracoes.CaminhoVirtual + "Controles/Redimensiona.ashx?img=" + Configuracoes.CaminhoVirtual + "images/equipe/" + pUnidadeCE + "/";

    if (!objEquipe.Listar(objEquipe)) return "";

    var depoimentos = objEquipe.lstEquipe.Skip(pIndex).Take(pLimite);

    var objJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(depoimentos.Aggregate("", (current, equipe) =>
            current + ("<div class='col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3'><img src='" + CaminhoImagem + equipe.EquipeImagem + "&w=400&h=400' alt='" + equipe.EquipeNome + "' class='img-circle img_perfil'><div class='nome_perfil text-center'>" + equipe.EquipeNome + "</div></div>")));

    return objJson;
}
```

Using like this i get a 401 Not Authorized and if i try to use my full URL `http://site/school-name/Default.aspx/BuscaEquipe` i get a 404.

P.S. I have already used this same method in another project and it worked fine but i can't figure out what's wrong in this one, i think it might be related to the URl but i'm not sure.

Comment: did you include [WebMethod] in frond of your web method ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV, yes i have and i can't even reach the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with your URL

Use the ResolveClientUrl() method

```
<%= ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx/BuscaEquipe") %>
```

And you must Have  [WebMethod] attribute before your static server function

```
[WebMethod]
public static string BuscaEquipe(int pIndex, int pLimite, int pUnidadeCE)
{
   //Code
}
```

Your data:

var requestData= JSON.stringify({
   pIndex: pIndex,
   pLimite: 4, 
   pUnidadeCE: codigoEmitente
})

and then

```
data:requestData
```

Comment: Got an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'BuscaEquipe' and i'm debugging and it didn't reach the method

Comment: do you change your ajax post like this

 `url:'<%= ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx/BuscaEquipe") %>',` ?

Comment: Yes i have, i put it on the Default.aspx page to be sure that the ResolveUrl would work

Comment: I forgot to put " around the resolveUrl, now it kind of works but i get a 500

Comment: @Terkhos take a look to my update.

if it's a 500 error so it is a prob with params name or type. Use the JSON.stringify as i mentionned

Comment: It worked, kind of ! Now i have a 401 ! What the heck is wrong with this project ! :O

Comment: What is the problem now ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72232/discussion-between-terkhos-and-med-amine-touil).